# How to restrict SIP traffic with tp-link TL-R600VPN router

Tags: firewall, voip, sip

I need to restrict incoming SIP/VoIP traffic from outside my network to a specific domain. I have a cloud SIP/VoIP system with 2 phones and I'm being inundated with fake/ghost calls (dead air when picked up). I have a tp-link Archer C7 router and I couldn't figure out how to do that so I just purchased a tp-link TL-R600VPN router/firewall but I can't figure out how to do that there either.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you:https://www.onsip.com/voip-resources/voip-solutions/disable-sip-alg-and-forward-nat-ports-to-stop-dropped-calls

Comment: Typically this should not be a problem unless you (probably unnecessary) forwarded 5060 port or enabled something like DMZ.
First thing you need to check is whether calls come from semi-random IP or from your PABX/provider.